# Button in a PropertyGrid

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

Is there a way to set a property as a button or add a button to a property? Looking through the grid sample I noticed that you can do something such as

```
wxPGEditor* editorButton = wxPropertyGrid::RegisterEditorClass(someButton);
propertyGrid->SetPropertyEditor(wxT("Name"), editorButton );
```

However, I would like to have different buttons, not just one type, which this would support.

**EDIT**:
By different buttons, I mean buttons that do not have to piggy back off of using an editor. What I would like to do is set an onClick call back function like you typically would for a wxButton, but set it as a property.

**EDIT2**: To be clear, I would like the property field its self to only be a button.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by 'different buttons'.

Answer (score 4):

You'd have to create a custom wxPGEditor that relays the button event based on data stored in the property.
The wxPGProperty can store user defined data (`wxClientData`) which can be used to store a callback function.

First you have to define the function signature of the handler that will be called on the button event.

```
typedef bool (wxEvtHandler::*ButtonEventMethod)(wxPGProperty*);
```

The handler receives the attached property as parameter and should return true if the property was modified.

Now a class based on wxClientData is required to store the callback:

```
struct ButtonData : wxClientData {
    ButtonData(ButtonEventMethod method, wxEvtHandler* handler)
        : _method(method), _handler(handler) {}
    bool call(wxPGProperty* property) {
        return (*_handler.*_method)(property);
    }
private:
    ButtonEventMethod _method;
    wxEvtHandler* _handler;
};
```

This class simply stores the address of the method and the class it belongs to. The editor will extract this object from the property and execute the `call()` method which in turn executes the callback:

```
class ButtonEventEditor : public wxPGTextCtrlAndButtonEditor {
protected:
    virtual bool OnEvent(wxPropertyGrid* propgrid, wxPGProperty* property,
        wxWindow* wnd_primary, wxEvent& event) const {
            // handle the button event
            if( event.GetEventType() == wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED )
                // extract the client data from the property
                if( ButtonData* btn = dynamic_cast<ButtonData*>(property->GetClientObject()) )
                    // call the method
                    return btn->call(property);
            return wxPGTextCtrlAndButtonEditor::OnEvent(propgrid,property,wnd_primary,event);
    }
};
```

To wrap it up, a function to "bind" a method to a property can be written:

```
void BindButton(wxPGProperty* property, ButtonEventMethod method, wxEvtHandler* handler) {
    property->SetClientObject(new ButtonData(method,handler));
}
```

And a macro to make it even simpler:

```
#define BIND_BUTTON(property,method,handler,editor) \
    property->SetEditor(editor); \
    BindButton(property,static_cast<ButtonEventMethod>(method),handler)
```

Now you can bind member functions to the properties:

```
// register the editor
wxPGEditor* editor = propertyGrid->RegisterEditorClass(new ButtonEventEditor());

// create a property
wxPGProperty* prop = propertyGrid->Append(new wxStringProperty("StringProperty"));

// bind method foo to the property
BIND_BUTTON(prop,&Frame::foo,this,editor);
```

And the method `foo` could look like this:

```
bool Frame::foo(wxPGProperty* p) {
    p->SetValue("foo");
    return true;
}
```

This is just an example to demonstrate how the wxPGProperty can store the callback (instead of creating multiple wxPGEditors). The callback storage (here ButtonData) could be modified to store an [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) or [`boost::function`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/function.html) instead (which would require C++11 or boost).

An alternative approach would be to store the callback information in the wxPGEditor instance. However, that would require multiple editor instances, one for each different callback function.

---

**UPDATE**

> the actual "button" does not show up until you click in the string field

The editor is not activated until the property is selected.
You would have to create a custom `wxPGProperty` returning a custom `wxPGCellRenderer` to take control over the representation of the property (while it is not being edited). 
Unfortunately, this would create an illusion and require the user to click the button twice: First to activate the property (and the editor) and then the actual button.
One solution that comes to mind is either displaying a text like `Click to edit` in the cell or a short summary of the property value.

While it is possible to have the custom property create a button and ignore the editor system, the property grid is not designed to work that way and this 'hack' may cause some problems. However, i added that hack at the end.

> there is a string field, when I just want the button to take up the entire property

That is just a side effect from the editor i used as base class for the example and it's easy to change. Since the wxTextCtrl is not needed, simply base the
editor on `wxPGEditor` directly and create the controls (a single button) yourself:

```
class ButtonEventEditor : public wxPGEditor {
protected:
    virtual wxPGWindowList CreateControls(wxPropertyGrid* propgrid, 
        wxPGProperty* property, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size) const {
            // create and return a single button to be used as editor
            // size and pos represent the entire value cell: use that to position the button
            return wxPGWindowList(new wxButton(propgrid,wxPG_SUBID1,"Edit",pos,size));
    }
    // since the editor does not need to change the primary control (the button)
    // to reflect changes, UpdateControl is just a no-op
    virtual void UpdateControl(wxPGProperty* property, wxWindow* ctrl) const {}
    // and here we remove the call to the base class because it is abstract
    virtual bool OnEvent(wxPropertyGrid* propgrid, wxPGProperty* property,
        wxWindow* wnd_primary, wxEvent& event) const {
            if( event.GetEventType() == wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED )
                if( ButtonData* btn = dynamic_cast<ButtonData*>(property->GetClientObject()) )
                    return btn->call(property);
            return false;
    }
};
```

> with this method, it seems there could only be one property editor

If you mean total: `wxPropertyGrid::RegisterEditorClass` simply registers an editor with the property grid (the grid will take ownership of the editor and automatically delete it when the property grid is destroyed). You can register as many editors as you like. You set the editor to a specific property, not the entire property grid.

If you mean at the same time: yes, unfortunately only one property editor can be active at any given time.

---

**The hack**

Let me finish this up with the hack i previously mentioned.

First we need a custom `wxPGCellRenderer` to position the button on the property grid:

```
class ButtonMover : public wxPGCellRenderer {
public:
    // pointer to the button from the property
    ButtonMover(wxButton* btn) : _btn(btn) {}
protected:
    virtual bool Render(wxDC &dc, const wxRect &rect, 
        const wxPropertyGrid *propertyGrid, wxPGProperty *property, 
        int column, int item, int flags) const {
            if( column == 0 ) { // 0 = label, 1 = value
                // instead of actually drawing the cell,
                // move the button to the cell position:
                wxRect rc(rect);
                // calculate the full property width
                rc.SetWidth(propertyGrid->GetClientRect().width-rect.GetX());
                _btn->SetSize(rc); // move button
                _btn->Show(); // initially hidden, show once 'rendered' (moved)
            }
            return true;
    }
private:
    wxButton* _btn;
};
```

Now we can create the custom property:

```
class ButtonProperty : public wxPGProperty {
public:
    // [parent] should be the property grid
    // [func] is the event handler
    // [button] is the button label
    // [label] is the property display name (sort name with autosort)
    // [name] is the internal property name
    ButtonProperty(wxWindow* parent, wxObjectEventFunction func,
        const wxString& button, const wxString& label=wxPG_LABEL,
        const wxString& name=wxPG_LABEL) 
        : wxPGProperty(label,name), _btn(new wxButton(parent,wxID_ANY,button)), 
            _renderer(_btn) {
                // connect the handler to the button
                _btn->Connect(wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED,func);
                _btn->Hide(); // when it's off the grid, it's not rendered 
                              // (thus not moved properly)
    }
protected:
    virtual wxPGCellRenderer* GetCellRenderer(int column) const {
        return &_renderer; // return button mover
    }
    virtual const wxPGEditor* DoGetEditorClass () const {
        return 0; // not using an editor
    }
private:
    wxButton* _btn; // the button attached to the property
    mutable ButtonMover _renderer; // the button mover
};
```

Having removed the need for an editor, you can now attach the event handler directly to the property:

```
propertyGrid->Append( new ButtonProperty(
    propertyGrid, // parent window
    wxCommandEventHandler(Frame::OnClick1), // event handler
    "Click me!") // button label
);

propertyGrid->Append( new ButtonProperty(
    propertyGrid,
    wxCommandEventHandler(Frame::OnClick2), 
    "Edit this!")
);
```

And the handlers would look like this:

```
void OnClick1(wxCommandEvent& event) {
    //TODO ...
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I am using wxPGEditor, however, I would like to have multiple buttons and not just one type of action (such as them being an editor). I just want the button press to call a function, such as wxButton onClick would do. I have gone through the property grid example, which shows what you are talking about, however, that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: This is close, however, there are two thing, maybe three, that prevent it from being what I was looking for. The first being is that the actual "button" does not show up until you click in the string field. The second being that there is a string field, when I just want the button to take up the entire property. The third is that with this method, it seems there could only be one property editor.

Comment: @mmurphy i have updated my answer and included an alternative approach that should do exactly what you're looking for (at the end of the update). However, it is a hack and i can not guarantee that it won't cause any problems.